# I make a song of silence

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

I make a song of silence,
so sit and listen well.

I hold in beasts of many kinds
far from where they dwell.

I've taken some peculiar things,
like artifacts and faces.

I have thick skin and spent some time
in a kitchen, of all places.

I am a place for some to get
their training for the Show.

If you can tell me who I am, 
then feel free to let me know.

Comment: The first line makes me think of "[The Sound of Silence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9Dg-g7t2l4)", covered recently by Disturbed, and created by Simon & Garfunkel.

Comment: Actually I am keeping it the way I had it. I don't think it's explicitly incorrect

Comment: But you can hold in a fart and you're not holding within a fart :)

Comment: That makes one of us.

Comment: If you would like to format this as poetry, you can do so. To preserve linebreaks, add two spaces to the end of each line. Then you won't need the double-spacing.

Comment: I mostly like this question because there are so many plausible answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> a Cage

---

I make a song of silence, so sit and listen well.

> John Cage wrote 4′33″ a song of just silence

I hold in beasts of many kinds far from where they dwell.

> Animals are held in cages at a zoo

I've taken some peculiar things, like artifacts and faces.

> Nicolas Cage was in National Treasure (artifacts) and Face/Off (faces)

I have thick skin and spent some time in a kitchen, of all places.

> Luke Cage (from Jessica Jones) has impenetrable skin (Thick Skin) and lives in Hell's Kitchen

I am a place for some to get their training for the Show.

> (From Todd Wilcox) "The Show" is a phrase used to refer to Major League Baseball, especially by baseball players in the minor leagues. You might practice in a batting cage to become good enough to "go to The Show"

If you can tell me who I am, then feel free to let me know.

> feel free - uncaged

Comment: Right answer but training clue is wrong

Comment: The Show is capitalized...

Comment: Still can't work out what "the Show" clue means, anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a fitness power cage for a bodbuilding show?

Comment: "The Show" is a phrase used to refer to Major League Baseball, especially by baseball players in the minor leagues. You might practice in a **batting cage** to become good enough to "go to The Show" (be picked up by a major league team).

Comment: @ToddWilcox, never heard of that before (no MLB here), but  that sounds right to me.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Nicely done

Answer (score 19):

Yup. It definitely is:

> A butt

**Reasoning:**

I make a song of silence, so sit and listen well.

> A fart silent and deadly, or a musical toot. Your butt also sits.

I hold in beasts of many kinds far from where they dwell.

> As I realized after commenting, some farts may be beastly demons escaped from hell. You also sometimes try to hold them in.

I've taken some peculiar things, like artifacts and faces.

> Careful what you shove up your butt. I'm sure someone has tried to smuggle an artifact that way before. Also, brown-nosers.

I have thick skin and spent some time in a kitchen, of all places.

> A butt may have thick skin, and definitely is with you in the kitchen. [Some people](https://www.reference.com/food/call-end-loaf-bread-1085d9b955f9e151) refer to the end slice of a loaf of bread as the "butt", in which case the thick skin could also refer to the crust.

I am a place for some to get their training for the Show.

> If you practice twerking, or are training sitting down watching how-to videos.

If you can tell me who I am, then feel free to let me know.

Comment: Fantastic answer butt sadly not correct

Comment: "definitely". Now that's confidence!

Answer (score 8):

> A book?

I make a song of silence,
so sit and listen well.

> Book doesn't make a noise but tells a story

I hold in beasts of many kinds
far from where they dwell.

> Stories can be about beasts

I've taken some peculiar things,
like artifacts and faces.

> Stories can hold people and artefacts

I have thick skin and spent some time
in a kitchen, of all places.

> The cover and a cookbook

I am a place for some to get
their training for the show.

> Educational books

If you can tell me who I am, 
then feel free to let me know.

> You're a book

Comment: Good answers but not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You're

> Film

---

I make a song of silence, so sit and listen well.

> Maybe this is a stretch but my answer implies light- and sound-waves are used analogously here.

I hold in beasts of many kinds far from where they dwell.

> Images of creatures, tourists taking pictures of animals

I've taken some peculiar things, like artifacts and faces.

> Photos of artifacts and faces, peculiar things

I have thick skin and spent some time in a kitchen, of all places.

> Film can be like a thick skin. In a kitchen we may have film developed as photos on the fridge or elsewhere, and there are various films used in food storage (e.g. thin plastic films like *Saran wrap*)

I am a place for some to get their training for the show.

> Admiring film as movies or photos for educational purposes

If you can tell me who I am, then feel free to let me know.

Comment: Not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a good answer - thanks for using spoilers and explaining yourself!

Answer (score 4):

I think it is...

> An oven (aka a cooker, a range; usually with stove on top).

---

I make a song of silence, so sit and listen well.

> It hums (fan +/ heater of the oven), and you have to wait for alarm that tells you the food is ready.

I hold in beasts of many kinds far from where they dwell.

> You can prepare nutritious meals in an oven using edible parts of any and all animals (e.g. a cow from your farm, or a kangaroo from your cousin's farm in Australia), some of which are wild and scary. (Pheasants! = Evil bird-creatures jumping at you out of nowhere.)

I've taken some peculiar things, like artifacts and faces.

> It can be used to dry pottery, crafts, etc. 'Peculiar' because you would not eat your ceramic bowl made in the pottery kiln (oven), but you can eat your oven-cooked lasagna. You use ovens to bake cookies, cakes, pizza etc, where the dough serves as a round flat surface symbolising a 2D face of a person when common features such as sugar eyes, nose and mouth are added/ drawn (pareidolia). There's a face-shaped cookie cutter and gingerbread man Christmas tradition.

I have thick skin and spent some time in a kitchen, of all places.

> Now, thick skin could be referring to the 'armour shield' build of the oven to protect the house from melting around it; or that lots of wild animals that can be cooked in the oven, have thick hide to protect them from the cold, dehydration, and attacks from predators. Pork rinds are a crispy oven-roasted (or fried) thick chunks of pigs' skin. Ovens are most probably located in a kitchen part of the house, and it's not surprising but 'faces' needed a rhyme.

I am a place for some to get their training for the Show.

> "Great British Bake Off" and all the cooking shows on TV. Some of the shows are competitive, so if a person wanted to win by cooking the best meat pie or the most delicious triple chocolate brownies, they would have to practice cooking and baking those meals in the oven before the competition.

If you can tell me who I am, then feel free to let me know.

---

Yes, feel free to let me know if you are who I think you are ;)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a great answer - thank you for using spoilers and explaining yourself. I hope to see you around here a lot more! c:

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest

> a Knife

---

I make a song of silence, so sit and listen well.

> a knife is stealthy

I hold in beasts of many kinds far from where they dwell.

> The animals may be scared of a knife wielding person

I've taken some peculiar things, like artifacts and faces.

> Knifes separate many things

I have thick skin and spent some time in a kitchen, of all places.

> Metal can be thick, and a kitchen is a great place to find a knife

I am a place for some to get their training for the show.

> The cooking show, Chopped!

If you can tell me who I am, then feel free to let me know.

Comment: Good answer, but not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say

> Ice

---

A song of silence...

> Ice is pretty silent

Hold in beasts

> Stores meat

Taken some peculiar things

> Cryogenic storage?

Thick skin, spent time in a kitchen

> Water *does* have a skin and therefore so will ice. Ice kept in a freezer in a kitchen.

A place for some to get their training

> Athletes etc take ice baths

Answer (score 0):

> A cookie jar.

---

I make a song of silence, so sit and listen well.

> Most inanimate objects are pretty silent, so this could be a red herring.

I hold in beasts of many kinds far from where they dwell.

> Animal crackers!

I've taken some peculiar things, like artifacts and faces.

> Pinterest is probably full of cookies decorated with faces.

I have thick skin and spent some time in a kitchen, of all places.

> Large stoneware or glass containers are pretty thick, and the kitchen is exactly where I'd expect a cookie jar.

I am a place for some to get their training for the Show.

> Well, a snack gives you energy to do a show. Or kids could use the animal / face cookies as puppets. (Then eat them, of course.)

If you can tell me who I am, then feel free to let me know.